# How to add objects to object repository automatically using vb scripts?

Tags: object, vbscript

Is it possible to add objects to an object repository automatically using VBScript?

Let's say I have list of links in my webpage/application. It would be time consuming, when I add objects manually so I tried to add objects to repository automatically. But couldn't able to proceed as I don't know how to activate object repository (during run time) in QTP.

Below is my code which I tried:

```
Function Objects_Count(myObject)
  Dim Objects
  Set Objects=Description.Create
  Objects("micclass").value=myObject
  set obj=Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").ChildObjects(Objects)
  For i=0 to obj.count-1
    'msgbox i
    c=obj(i).getroproperty("name")
    If obj(i).Exist(1) Then
      obj(i).highlight
    End If
    Print c
  Next
End Function
Call Objects_Count("link")
```

The above code will get the links name displayed in a log file and also it will highlight in application/webpage. Please guide me how to add the properties of that links(objects)  to object repository.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to manipulate the object repository, you'll need the `Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil` object, `load` an existing object repository and add an object to it using `AddObject`.

```
Set myRepository = CreateObject("Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil")
myRepository.Load "C:\QuickTest\Tests\Flights.tsr"
myRepository.AddObject myLink, Browser("B").Page("P"), "myLinkName"
```

You'll have to play with it a bit to get it working in your situation. Use the QTP help to find out all accessible methods/properties of the ObjectRepositoryUtil, just enter "ObjectRepositoryUtil" in the search box underneath the `Index` tab.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** You need to create the test object by its [ProgId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542719.aspx) not by its `micclass`.

Then use `SetTOProperty` in order to create the relevant description from the values returned by `ChildObjects`.

See this [question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613543/).

---

<s>I don't believe there is a way to add a test object dynamically. `ObjectRepositoryUtil.AddObject` has this in its documentation:</s>

> You can use this method to add a copy of an object that you retrieved from a different object repository.

You can dynamically create a repository via XML with the properties fetched in your test but I think this is more bother than it's worth.

Probably best to use descriptive programming in this case.

For more details see this [LinkedIn thread](https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/1079537-262719920).